# Quantas vezes uma string aparece em uma tabela em cada registro (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, xml, count

Tenho uma tabela no SQL com uma coluna chamada "conteudo", do tipo varchar . Essa coluna armazena o conteúdo de XMLs.

Preciso contar o número de vezes que uma certa palavra (tag) está em cada XML, ou seja, para cada registro dessa tabela.

Alguém saberia como me ajudar? SOS

Answer (score 1):

Cara...acho que a maneira mais fácil de ser feita, vai ser essa aqui ó:

```
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(50) =  'TAG'
SELECT (LEN(CAMPOXML) - LEN(REPLACE(CAMPOXML,@VAR,''))) / LEN(@VAR)
```

Você pega o tamanho do campo

`>> LEN(CAMPO)`

depois faz um replace para tirar a palavra que você quer encontrar e vê qual o tamanho que ele ficou:

`>> LEN(REPLACE(CAMPO,@VAR,''))`

subtrai para saber qual a diferença de caracteres:

`>> (LEN(CAMPO) - LEN(REPLACE(CAMPO,@VAR,'')))`

e por último vc divide pelo tamanho da variável (palavra que vc quer encontrar), para retornar a quantidade.

Comment: Obrigada! Essa função LEN, aceita como argumento o nome de uma coluna de uma view? Ocorre que quando executo , o SQL me diz Invalid column name

Comment: Sim, aceita. Edite a resposta e adicione um print do erro/verifique se o nome da coluna está mesmo correta.

Comment: Fala Pedro, como ta? Sobre sua dúvida de pq a pergunta foi fechada, pois, acredito eu, que o usuário não  forneceu nenhum código e sim pediu um código, seria como: 'e ai pedro, faz um hello word pra mim em python?' Claro que para quem entende python é muito simples fazer, porém não é este o propósito do site, e sim ajuda-lo: 'pq vc nao conseguiu fazer o hello word?' qual duvida vc tem?' entendeu? Dê uma lida nestes links:  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6252/110782

Comment: já já eu apago o comentario :D

Comment: Não vou negativar a resposta porque está correta, porem esse parece ser um problema do tipo façam para mim onde o acadêmico não está com vontade de fazer seus deveres de casa e posta aqui na expectativa de que alguém faça a lição para ele de graça. Para filtrar esses casos de perguntas legítimas a comunidade instituiu um filtro o [MCVE] também conhecido como \[MCVE\], que nada mais é do que um pedido de prova da legitimidade da pergunta.

Comment: Outra coisa quando tiver esse tipo de reclamação. Faça no canal competente que é o [META](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/) onde as perguntas são sobre o funcionamento do site, perguntas a comunidade, bugs, propostas de melhorias e novos recursos.